# My scale factor is affecting my speed on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, speed

So, whenever I adjust my scale factor, 200% for example. It'll get slower. If it was set to 100%, then it runs perfectly smooth. Im confused as to why this happens. As of writing I'm using VirtualBox for the first time and I kinda don't know what Im doing.

Comment: What device are you using (Macbook, PC etc?) and if using a laptop, are you using that screen or outputting to external monitor?

Comment: Why do you mention VirtualBox? Does the issue affect VMs only? Is the scaling enabled in a VM or the host?

Comment: Heya, for starters I'm using a MacBook Air. I'm using the little app that comes with downloading Virtual. Sorry if that isn't a 100% answer, I'm unfamiliar with the proper terms and all that. Second, I mention VirtualBox mostly because this is the first VM I'm using and just incase the type of machine I was using mattered.  I don't know if this happens with others. Again, I'm unfamiliar with the proper terms so if this doesn't answer the question its my bad. Anyway, I input the scaling through the host via the app that lets me start the machine itself.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, you're running a Windows 10 guest on a macOS host using VirtualBox. You're also using some tool to enable scaling in the guest and when you do, the guest is slow. Is that correct? What's the tool you're using? Can you post a screenshot? Why not just enable scaling in Windows? Are Guest Additions installed and is 3D acceleration enabled?

Comment: Yup, all that's right. It's not exactly a tool, rather built in to the VirtualBox app itself under settings, specifically display. I'd post a screenshot but I'm unaware how on here. I don't believe I can scale Windows inside of it as far as I'm aware. I can't find  the "Guest Additions" and as for 3D, well the option to enable it is greyed out. I'm also unsure as to why.

Answer (score 0):

So after following a tutorial and adjusting some things, I got the VM to work normally now. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IvLm_PZJDz0 Credits to him.